# What is the maximum magnetic field that a human body can withstand?

Tags: magnetic-fields, biophysics, biology

Are there limits to the exposure of human bodies to magnetic fields? What happens if we cross that limit? How to create such magnetic fields? Has this been tried out?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about human physiological response to magnetic fields not physics

Comment: @JohnRennie unless of course we go to the point of spin-polarizing every electron shell in the body :D then there's not much physiology left

Comment: um....you could have answered the question in the mean time right...

Comment: there's always google http://www.greenfacts.org/en/static-fields/index.htm#4

Comment: related question here:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61679/  and here's a very nice article on the subject.   https://gravityandlevity.wordpress.com/2015/01/12/how-strong-would-a-magnetic-field-have-to-be-to-kill-you/   The short answer is, it would take an enormous amount of magnetism to do a person any real harm.

Comment: @userLTK thanks for the great link.....magnetars huh....:)

Comment: As people who have been near (or imaged in) 7T MRI scanners know, the _changing_ field (for example, from going _into_ the magnet) can be quite disorienting long before the _static_ field does any damage, because of the induced macroscopic currents. If you suddenly lean across the table of a 7T scanner, close to the bore, you risk falling and cracking your skull.

Comment: cracking the skull because of falling down?